# How to create list from two joined tables when foreign key is not required but still need to get all records

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, code-first

I have a simple DB structure. Navigation property to Owner class, and I meet a problem when I am trying to creat transport list with added OwnerName from Owner because OwnerID in Transport is not required...

```
public Transport()
{
        [Key]
        public int TransportID { get; set; }
        public string PlateNo { get; set; }
        public string Brand { get; set; }
        public string OwnerID { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("OwnerID")]
        public virtual Owner Owner { get; set;} 

        [NotMapped]
        public string OwnerName { get; set; }
 } 

public partial class Owner
 {
        [Key]
        public string OwnerID { get; set; }
        public string OwnerName { get; set; }
 }

var result = (from n in Transports select new Transport()
 {TransportID=n.TransportID,
  OwnerID = n.OwnerID, 
  OwnerName = n.Owner.OwnerID
 }).ToList();
```

While executing query I get System.NullReferenceException: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
I need a transport list event if it doesn't have Owner...

Comment: What is `Transports`? If it's EF queryable, you shouldn't be getting NRE. Also you shouldn't be able to use `select new Transport`.

Comment: First of all I am trying to filter DBContext.Transports entity because of a big amount if data... so I get filtered list for e.g. Transports = DBContext.Transports.Where(t=>t.TransportID == someValue).toList()

Comment: If is a list, then the question is unrelated to EF.

Comment: Understood... Actually I am trying to write LinQ.. but I am tired because this query tooks so long ant looking how to make it faster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 var result = (from n in transports
                          select new Transport()
                          {
                              TransportID = n.TransportID,
                              OwnerID = n.OwnerID,
                              OwnerName = n.Owner?.OwnerName
                          }).ToList();
```

Using Null-conditional Operator will help to avoid NRE.

Comment: Will try on monday!!

Comment: I get OwnerID but null in OwnerName :(

Answer (score 1):

You have to check if the Owner is null or not in your query.
Modify your line:

```
OwnerName = n.Owner.OwnerID
```

to this:

```
OwnerName = n.Owner == null ? "" : n.Owner.OwnerID
```

Comment: Here I get null in OwnerName field even if OwnerId is not null

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = (from n in Transports.Include("Owner") select new Transport()
             {TransportID=n.TransportID,
              OwnerID = i.OwnerID, 
              OwnerName = i.Owner.OwnerID
             }).ToList();
```